# SSH connection for IDEA's git integration on Windows 10

Tags: git, bash, intellij-idea, ssh

ver 2017 ultimate Intellij IDEA freshly installed on win machine, trying to clone a project from a private git repo over ssh getting "clone failed could not read from remote repo" in IDEA, but I can clone the same repo from win git bash. here is the procedure I followed in IDEA

1. Settings -> version control -> add git and set configure VCS to Native
2. I already have my id_rsa in user/.ssh folder
3. Git is already enabled in Intellij

on intellij site it says"configure a platform-specific ssh-askpass to receive prompts for passwords" no idea where is that.

any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git Bash is standalone bash, IDEA cannot use it, so the fact clone works from there does not mean it will work from IDEA.

The valid test here would be to clone from Windows Command Prompt. Does it work?

Native SSH executable means that IDEA expects git to establish SSH connection on its own. In this mode, IDE does not handle any prompts, so if you are prompted for a password or SSH-key passphrase, it will fail.

Try the Built-in SSH executable.

Comment: intellij does prompt me for password for the repo I checked again, but I have only the key.

Comment: restarted intellij and changed to Built-in and it picked up the id_rsa key all working